# trying to set new state with function in componentDidMount: this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I have a `setTimout` function called `fetchUsers` that returns users after 5 seconds. I am trying to call `fetchUsers` inside componentDidMount to then update the users state. The error I am getting is `this.setState` is not a function. How can I properly update the state of users in the `componentDidMount` function?

```
var App = React.createClass({

  fetchUsers: function(cb){
    setTimeout(function(){
       cb([{name: 'joe'}, {name: 'john'}, {name: 'jim'}])
    }, 1000)
  },

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      users: [],
      loaded: false,
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.fetchUsers(function(users){
      console.log(users);
      this.setState({
        users: users,
        loaded: true
      })
    })
  },

  render: function(){
    if(!this.state.loaded){
      return (
        <div>
          <p> Loading.... </p>
        </div>
        )
    };
    var users = this.state.data.map(function(user){
        return <li> {user.name} </li>
    });

    return(
        <div>
          <h3> Look at my users.. </h3>
          <ul> {users} </ul>
        </div>
      )
  }

})

React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('hello'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference to this is different. The following should work:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    this.fetchUsers(function(users){
      console.log(users);
      this.setState({
        users: users,
        loaded: true
      })
    }.bind(this))
}
```